# Need help iterating through a dictionary - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I'm a beginner in Python. 
I have a simple dictionary called G8_Leaders.txt - as follows: {Cameron:UK, Merkel:Germany, Obama:USA, Putin:Russia} 
and I'm trying to iterate through the pairs - display the contents in a column, using a basic "for" loop like so:

```
f0 = "G8_Leaders.txt"
f1 = open(f0)
    for i in f1:
        print(i, end=" ")
    else:
        print("Finished with Document: ", f0)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I'd like the results in a column, such as:

Merkel Germany

Cameron UK

Obama USA

and so on...However, the results are only printed in one line, as they are displayed in the text file.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: In python, doing `for xyz in <file object>` will iterate through the file one *line* at a time. If you want to get an actual python dictionary you'll need to use something like the `json` module to load the file contents into a usable python object.

Comment: You really have two different problems here: 1.) How do I parse a text file into a python dictionary? 2.) How do I iterate through a python dictionary, printing one pair at a time?

Comment: what do you mean by "I have a simple dictionary called G8_Leaders.txt "..? a text file is not a dictionary. it is a text file. do you mean that the text inside of it is in that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to fix the representation of your dictionary in your file to be as:

`d = {'Cameron':'UK', 'Merkel':'Germany', 'Obama':'USA', 'Putin':'Russia'}`
It can be done programmatically by invoking `str()` on each key and value of `d`.
Assuming that that is fixed, one solution would be:

```
# Create a file for test bench: 
d = {'Cameron':'UK', 'Merkel':'Germany', 'Obama':'USA', 'Putin':'Russia'}
with open("G8_Leaders.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(d) +'\n')

#Read and print from the file:
with open("G8_Leaders.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    d = eval(line)
    for y, z in d.items():
        print(y, z)
```

Output:

```
Cameron UK
Merkel Germany
Putin Russia
Obama USA
```

Comment: @Cain: Since you are new here, as a reminder, don't forget to accept and upvote the answer you decide on.

Comment: I forgot to mention: It ran just fine in py 2.x. I'm primarily using python 3.5 and it didn't like the absence of parens in the final print statement, and apparently "iteritems" attribute has been replaced by "items" in py 3.x. So it's working now as expected in py 3.x. It is interesting that in py 2.x the results are placed into a column of tuples, whereas py 3.x displays them exactly as I wanted - in a clean column without terminating brackets, parens, etc. Thank for your help! PS. I did upvote your answer, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple things are going on here. `f1` is a file object, which is not what you are expecting. If you want to access it as a string, you would do

```
`f1_string = f1.read()`
```

Which reads the file into the variable `f1_string` as a string. You could do:

```
for line in f1.readlines():
    # operate on one line at a time in this block
```

if you would prefer to read a line at a time, which will work in your case if each element is on its own line in the text file. Since we don't know what exactly what your text file looks like, it's hard to give more specific help. The `json` module people are referring to can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), but I'm not entirely sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your text file is just as you've described it, then try the following:

```
    with open(f0, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            items = line.split(',')
            for item in items:
                leader = item.split(':')[0].replace('{','')
                country = item.split(':')[1].replace('}','')
                print(leader,country)
```

This should work regardless of whether or not your data has line breaks in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to iterate through a dictionary:

```
leaders = {'Cameron':'UK', 'Merkel':'Germany', 'Obama':'USA', 'Putin':'Russia'}
for leader in leaders:    
    print(leader, leaders[leader])
```

Comment: Btw the results are printed in one line because of the end= " " in your code! Just delete it and you will be fine :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
print("\n".join(x+"  "+ y for x,y in json.load(open("fname.txt" ,"rb")).iteritems()))
```

just load it as json(at least I think **its not entirely clear if you have properly formatted json** in your text file ) ... (warning though dictionaries are unordered so if you need a certain order you will have to provide more clarification)